# Keep the index from a list

Tags: python

If I have the following array:

```
T = array([[list([2])],
          [list([])],
          [list([0])]], dtype=object)
```

All I want to happen is when I type `T[0]`, I want the the index `[2]` to be returned. At present I get `array([list([2])], dtype=object.`

I don't want the list, the round brackets, the other text, I just want `[2]`.

## additional info below (edit)

I have a more complex case I'm wanting to try this out on but have created a simple example first to see if the concept works and is where I'm having trouble.
I have the following function in which you specify a set to search, and provide the set that has the elements in ti that you're looking for.
The function then returns the index in the main set of where the values were found.

```
find = lambda searchList, elem: [[i for i, x in enumerate(searchList) if     x == e] for e in elem]
```

My main set that I wanted to look into is composed of two string arrays, then joined together into a 3 x 2 array.

```
A = np.array([['A'], ['B'],['C'], ['D']])` # main set 1
array([['A'],
       ['B'],
       ['C'],
       ['D']],
      dtype='<U1')

D = np.array([['E'], ['F'],['G'], ['H']]) # main set 2

array([['E'],
       ['F'],
       ['G'],
       ['H']],
      dtype='<U1')


F = np.column_stack((A,D)) # Combined Array - The main set in which to look through using the find function.
array([['A', 'E'],
       ['B', 'F'],
       ['C', 'G'],
       ['D', 'H']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

I have done exactly the same with a made up search set (composed of two smaller sets)

```
C = np.array([['C'], ['D'], ['A']])

E = np.array([['G'], ['D'], ['E']])
G = np.ndarray.tolist(F)
```

I wanted to combine these into a single array and have them side by side, 3 rows, 2 columns.

```
H = np.column_stack((C,E))
array([['C', 'G'],
       ['D', 'D'],
       ['A', 'E']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

When I apply the find function, it does indeed return to me the indexes of where the elements are in the main array.

```
T = find(G, I)
array([list([2]), list([]), list([0])], dtype=object)
```

Now, I have created another array, which just has the number 1, 2, 3 and 4 in it

```
B = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

I wanted to use the indexes returned to me in the search function i.e.

```
[2], [] (blank) and [0]
```

Any pull the numbers from array B and store them in a separate array
i.e. I wanted `L = [3],[],[1]`

Using:
    L = np.empty([len(I),1])

```
for j in range(len(H)):
  L[j] = B[T[j]]
```

However I get the error:

```
L[j] = B[T[j]]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,1) into shape (1)
```

Comment: Please consider [To create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where is array coming from? Numpy?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just say `T=[2,'',0]`?

Comment: This goes much deeper, but if I can get this bit working I can manage the rest.
This is used in comparing strings in a filename against that in a master document and then returns the value next to a specified column in the master. The filenames change all the time as they relate to downloaded content.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to put in the definition of I. And it's a bit odd to create an anonymous function and then assign it to a variable. This really feels like an XY problem. It seems like `find` can return anything up to `len(G)-1`, and G has 6 elements but `B` has only 4 elements. If it weren't for that issue, it seems to me that two lines would do this: `lookup=pd.Series(B, index =G)`  `L = [[lookup[x] for x in G if x==y] for y in I]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly index the element.  Here are the various levels of your nested lists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> T = np.array([[list([2])],
...     [list([])],
...     [list([0])]], dtype=object)
>>> T
array([[[2]],
       [[]],
       [[0]]], dtype=object)
>>> T[0]
array([[2]], dtype=object)
>>> T[0][0]
[2]
>>> T[0][0][0]
2
```

See how that works?

If you want T[0] to be 2, then you need to make `2` the first element of the list, rather than a list containing the list containing 2.  For instance:

```
>>> S = np.array([2, None, 0])
>>> S
array([2, None, 0], dtype=object)
>>> S[0]
2
```

Comment: Hi there Prune, thank you very much :)
I'll give that a go and thanks for the speedy reply :D

Comment: Glad to help.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. This is my first time one here so I'l bear that in mind.
What I'm trying to do is store those values (the indexes) in another array. This list is dynamic and the number and value of the index shown will change frequently. So I'm trying to find a solution that will automatically retrieve these integers and store them.

Comment: Thanks very much I believe with the knowledge you shared I have managed to resolve the issue.  I changed B[ T[ j ] ] to B[ T[ j ] [0] ]

Answer (score -1):

A solution that works with the exact data given is T[0][0]; T[0] returns array([list([2])], and taking element zero of that returns [2] (and taking element zero of that returns 2). However, it's not clear what application this is for (and referring the [2] as an "index" raises red flags). It might be better to give a larger context, and get suggestions on how to accomplish your larger goal. For instance, if you store this as a Series or DataFrame, you can store [2] as a name, and then access it that way instead of drilling down several layers in the array.

Comment: I'm just typing this out in my notepad, the character limit might result in a few comments (I'm new to this, apologies).

Comment: I've just edited my main question so hopefully helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated, I managed to solve the issue as commented above. Thanks again.

Comment: See my earlier answer: you need three subscripts, not two.  The rest of your answer should be a comment on the main question.

Comment: @Prune the OP says they want `[2]` to be returned. That is achieved with two subscripts, not three.

Comment: I see ... the question has changed since I wrote my answer.  However, that is still contained within what I wrote; please call out what your answer (not the comments) adds to the discussion.